# Raspberry Pi の画面が逆さに表示されるのを解消したい

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 4Bと公式タッチディスプレイ (７インチ) を使用していますが、画面が逆さに表示されてしまいます。

他サイトでは /boot/config.txt に `lcd_rotate=2` を追記して再起動すれば解消できるとなっていましたが、解消しませんでした。
他に解消できる方法を知っておられたら教えて頂けませんか？

Comment: Raspberry Piには各種のディスプレイインターフェースがあります。micro-HDMI, SPI, high-speed DPI, コンポジット RCA (PAL / NTSC), MIPI DSI (もしかすると他にも) https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html
それから, (仮に Linux使ってるとしても)ディスプレイサーバーは X11の可能性もあるし, Waylandかもしれない。その他の可能性もある。(それによって指定が変わる可能性大)
… それでは回答付けようがないので, 質問に, 使用してる環境のことを記した方がよいでしょう

Comment: 「各種のディスプレイインターフェース」があっても公式タッチディスプレイがつながるインターフェースは決まってます。自分が使ってるのがXなのかWaylandなのかは普通の人にはわかりません。無駄に質問者を混乱させるだけのコメントになっています。環境の説明が必要なのであれば、質問者が何を書いたらいいのかわかるように指摘しましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[公式ドキュメント](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#rotating-your-display)をざっと見た程度ですが

`lcd_rotate=x`は旧製品での設定で、4B以降は設定方法が変わっているようです。

- デスクトップ環境を使っているのであれば、デスクトップの"Preferences"メニュー→"Screen Configuration Utility"で設定する。
- 非デスクトップ環境の場合は、/boot/cmdline.txtを編集して設定する。

旨が記載されています。